# What's the best way to do an existence check on a cookie with python/GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

In my code I'm using

```
user_id = self.request.cookies.get( 'user_id', '' )

if user_id != '':
        me = User.get_by_id( int( user_id ) )
```

but to me this doesn't look right even though it technically works...it looks imprecise. Is there a better way I can check for the existence of a cookie?

Answer (score 2):

I've never use AppEngine but I guess `request.cookies` is just a normal dictionary object like for example in Django. You can try the following:

```
if 'user_id' in self.request.cookies:
    # cookie exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and Except clauses are very handy for situations like this where you need a clear and obvious workflow with a hair trigger **invalidate everything** catch all.

To be clear, this does not approach the various nuances involved in securely tracking/managing a user session by leaving data on the client.

```
try:
  user_id = self.request.cookies['user_id'] #will raise a 'KeyError' exception if not set.
  if isinstance(user_id, basestring):
    assert user_id # will raise a 'ValueError' exception if user_id == ''.
    try:
      user_id = int(user_id)
    except ValueError:
      logging.warn(u'user_id value in cookie was of type %s and could not be '
        u'coerced to an integer. Value: %s' % (type(user_id), user_id))
  if not isinstance(user_id, int):
    raise AssertionError(u'user_id value in cookie was INVALID! '
      u'TYPE:VALUE %s:%s' % (type(user_id), user_id))
except KeyError:
  # 'user_id' key did not exist in cookie object.
  logging.debug('No \'user_id\' value in cookie.')
except AssertionError:
  # The cookie value was invalid!
  clear_the_cookie_and_start_again_probably()
except Exception, e:
  #something else went wrong!
  logging.error(u'An exception you didn\'t count on. Exception: %s' % e)
  clear_the_cookie_and_start_again_probably()
  raise e
else:
  me = User.get_by_id(user_id)
```

Comment: "To be clear, this does not approach the various nuances involved in securely tracking/managing a user session by leaving data on the client." How could I research this a bit more so I can understand those nuances?

Comment: Checkout the 'Client side web sessions' section of this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science).

Comment: For AppEngine you could look at gae-sessions, according to the website, it is "...a sessions library for the Python runtime on Google App Engine for ALL session sizes. It is extremely fast, lightweight (one file), and easy to use.". I use it myself and have not had a problem with it at all.